# WinForms: Is it a good practice to pass a reference of the parent control into multiple child controls

Tags: c#, winforms

I have the following pattern. There is a parent form with buttons in it and an abstract base class for creating child forms. Multiple child forms like `ChildForm1`, `ChildForm2` will be spawned from the `ParentForm` on events like pressing buttons etc. This is a simple representation of what I'm currently doing.

```
public partial class ParentForm : Form
{
    public ParentForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button1_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new ChildForm1(this).Show();
    }

    // Some other methods
}

public abstract partial class BaseChildForm : Form
{
    protected readonly Form _parent;

    public BaseChildForm(Form parent)
    {
        _parent = parent;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ThisForm_OnAppear(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Do some changes in the parent form through _parent field
    }

    // Some other methods as well
}

public partial class ChildForm1 : BaseChildForm
{
    public ChildForm1(Form parent) : base(parent){}

    // Overridden abstract methods and other methods
    // Do some tampering with the parent form
}

public partial class ChildForm2 : BaseChildForm
{
    public ChildForm2(Form parent) : base(parent){}

    // Overridden abstract methods and other methods
    // Do some tampering with the parent form
}
```

In this code, I actually want to access and control the behavior and other properties of the `ParentForm` when doing certain things in the child forms. But as you see the public members of the `ParentForm` are completely exposed to the child forms. Also, it can be an issue and cause unexpected results when multiple `ChildForm` instances manipulate the `ParentForm` at a given time.

So far, this pattern "*gets things done*" for me. But I wonder if there is any other better way to achieve my requirement?

Comment: Only one child form can access the parent form at a time. All the forms run in the same thread (the UI thread). Therefore, only one method (e.g. a Button_Click or Form_Load, etc.) can run at a given time. When the user clicks another button when the first Button_Click is running, the second one has to wait until the first one returns. Other threads are not allowed to access the UI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it is a good practice to expose the `ParentForm` to the child forms that much. **You can extract an interface** for the common `ParentForm` operations/properties, implement them in the `ParentForm` and inject the interface instance to the child forms as follows:

```
interface IParent
{
    int Property1 { get; set; }
    void Method1();
}

class ParentForm : Form, IParent
{
    public int Property1 { get; set; }

    public void Method1()
    {
        // Implementation here.
    }
}

class ChildForm1 : Form
{
    private readonly IParent parent;

    public ChildForm1(IParent parent)
    {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    // Use parent accordingly
}
```

Comment: Also, since the children are playing with GUI thread, and only one thing can manipulate the GUI thread at a time, the functions should use a synchronized list to hold the children, as well as sychronize the functions that might affect/propgate changes to the children. That will help with the children fighting.